# arithmetic within string literal in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Playing with Swift, I found something awkward error.

```
let cost = 82.5
let tip = 18.0
let str = "Your total cost will be \(cost + tip)"
```

This works fine as I expect, but

```
let cost = 82.5
let tip:Float = 18
let str = "Your total cost will be \(cost + tip)"
```

would not work with error

```
could not find member 'convertFromStringInterpolationSegment' 
let str = "Your total cost will be \(cost + tip)"
```

The difference between two example is declaring tip constant to explicitly float or not. Would this be reasonable result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to cast the numbers into the same type so they can be added together, e.g:

```
let cost = 82.5
let tip:Float = 18
let str = "Your total cost will be \(Float(cost) + tip)"
```

By default real number literals are inferred as `Double`, i.e:

```
let cost:Double = 82.5
```

So they need to be either explicitly cast to a `Double` or a `Float` to be added together.

Comment: Ehhh I guess floating point without explicit declaration will be treated as Double. That's why I need to cast Float on cost

Comment: @iPatel Because by default `let cost = 82.5` is inferred as a `Double` and that you can't explicitly add to a `Float`. There's also no operator overloading for `Double + Float` so that statement is illegal.

Comment: @mythz -Ohh,, yah,, thanks mate for more clarify me :)

Comment: Int + Double also doesn't work.. I would hope it would work as python

Comment: @iPatel by design, swift never does automatic type conversion of variables

Answer (score 1):

Values are never implicitly converted to another type.

```
let cost = 82.5
let tip:Float = 18
let str = "Your total cost will be \(cost + tip)"
```

In the above example it is considering cost as double & you have defined tip as float, so it is giving error.

Rather specify the type of cost as float as shown below

```
let cost:Float = 82.5
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `cost` in inferred to be of type `Double`.

In your first (working) example `tip` is also inferred to be `Double` and the expressions `cost + tip` is an addition of two `Double` values, resulting in a `Double` value.

In your second (not working) example `tip` is declared to be `Float` therefore the expressions `cost + tip` is an error.
The error message is not very informative. But the problem is that you are adding a `Double` to a `Float` and in a strongly statically typed language you will not have automatic type conversions like you had in C or Objective C.

You have to do either `Float(cost) + tip` or `cost + Double(tip)`